# Replace null values in a query that returns multiple values where only some of them are null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, null, ssms

Is there a way to replace every instance of null in a query?

I am using SQL Server 2008. For example if a query returns 4 values:

**CustomerName:**

```
Bob   
Joe    
Null    
Alice
```

Can i replace the `Null` with `Allen` or any varchar/string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
SELECT CustomerName = COALESCE(CustomerName, 'Allen')
FROM dbo.TableName
```

If `NULL` isn't really `NULL` but the string `'NULL'` you can use [`NULLIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) + `COALESCE` / `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT CustomerName = COALESCE(NULLIF(CustomerName, 'NULL'), 'Allen')
FROM dbo.TableName
```

Comment: Thanks this worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
Coalesce(CustomerName, 'Allen')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: i did not downvote. i upvoted. However, my post was downvoted .

Comment: @Azuraith yes I figured that out. Your post was downvoted by somebody probably because this was asked before. But what I don't understand is downvoting valid answers without an explanation.

Comment: i dont think anyone downvoted your answer

Comment: @Azuraith yes they did. And the other answer too. (I can see +2/-1)